# Matplotlib heatmap rotates image automatically

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a series of coordinate data (latitude and longtitude).

I managed to created a nice heatmap out of the scatter plot of points but the plot seems to be rotated 90 degrees to the right... I can't figure out why that happens.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

x = coords.longtitude
y = coords.latitude

heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=30)
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]

plt.imshow(heatmap, extent=extent)
plt.show(p)
```

This is the result:
[image]

The perceptive one can see an image of the Netherlands... Only rotated.

Comment: You are lacking an import for coords, if your code is to be reproduced...

Comment: @Jblasco The coordinates contain sensitive data so I cannot show them unfortunately. It's a pandas dataframe.

Comment: I see. I thought you were reading from some public library. In cases like this, some people create a minimal example with a fake dataset, for example creating the arrays with with numpy.random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jblasco suggested, here is a minimal working example with fake data.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
p = plt.figure()
plt.style.use('ggplot')

np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.rand(50)
y = np.random.rand(50)

heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=4)
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]

plt.imshow(heatmap, extent=extent)
plt.show(p)
```

And here are both images with `np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=30)` and `np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=30)`

which of course rotates the image (actually, it transposes the image). Thus I don't understand your problem neither.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Ah but that one indeed works. Notice the subtle difference between `heatmap, yedges, xedges = np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=30)` and `np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=30)`. One transposes the entire data, the second only the histogram.

Comment: Yes, I got the axes wrong, sorry. Hats off to @Emiliien for faking data to show it.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation of numpy.histogram2D](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.htm)

> The bi-dimensional histogram of samples x and y. Values in x are histogrammed along the first dimension and values in y are histogrammed along the second dimension.

Which is exactly the opposite to what matplotlib does, where the first axis is the vertical one.  I suggest you transpose x and y when creating the heatmap.

Comment: Tried that a few times, but couldn't get anything useful out that.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What doesn't go well if you do: heatmap, yedges, xedges = np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=30)

Comment: The shape is even more unrecognizable :)